BNC panel connector nut position
I need to use this panel mount BNC for an enclosure.
My problem is I cannot figure out if the washer will be on the flange side or the nut side.
I cannot find any schematic or photo as well so I had to quick draw cross-sections myself.
Which one is correct?:
Figure 1

Figure 2


The washer is to be located on the nut side.


At the risk of being pedantic, this would assume that the hole in the bulkhead is the typical D-shaped hole, designed to prevent the BNC connector from spinning.  In that case the lock washer would indeed be on the nut side.  However, if the hole in the panel is just a simple round hole, then the position of the lock washer will collapse the wave function, and no matter which side you choose, the other side will always loosen first.  So, in that case, use 2 lock washers (and if things still loosen up, blame Einstein).  Of course, if it's a flat washer, then do whatever you think is best.

This answer is correct, but the general rules for where best to put a flat or lock washer in an assembly are actually a bit complex. Usually you want a lockwasher under the part that's turning to tighten the assembly to keep it from doing the opposite. But where two parts are potentially turning (think about a bolted connection with a nut driver on one side and a screwdriver or hex key on the other) you have to think about the friction on one side  vs. the other and put it on the more slippery side. And sometimes you want a flat washer.

We definitely need to run a simulation.  Please list all materials used, accurately dimensioned 3D models, and a list of all possible environmental conditions that the assembly will experience over its lifetime. (a dT of 30 seconds ought to be adequate).  ...or just stick it under the nut.
